# Hibernate (JPA) Entity with Static collection as a member

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

Is it possible to have a static collection as a member of a hibernate entity?

Say I have an object Question:

```
public class Question {
    private String category;

    ...
}
```

Would it be possible to populate a static Set<String> that is a distinct set of all categories in the Database?  I know I could just query this, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution, as it seems like something that other people may have come across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, JPA cannot persist `static` or `final` fields. The spec isn't very clear on this but it makes IMO sense since I don't see what would be the one in a `OneToXXX` relation (so how should JPA load it). You might want to check [the following thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=938860&start=0) for some feedback (i.e. not a final answer) from the ejb3 expert group. I'm afraid you'll have somehow to link all your `Question` with all `Category`.

But maybe you'll get more "satisfying" answers. Let's see.

Comment: I meant along the lines of a read only collection that pulled from a SELECT DISTINCT query.

Comment: @Kyle Yeah, I understand the idea but I don't know how to tell JPA to do that in a nice way. I'm very curious to see if you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Simple but not perfect solution would be using entity `@PostLoad` callback method on `Category` or `Question` entities (or both):

```
@Entity
public class Question {
  public static Set<String> categories = new HashSet<String>();
  ...

  @PostLoad
  public void fillInCategories() {
    categories.add(category);
  }

}
```

`categories` is lazy loaded - until all questions that contain every category are loaded it won't be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use property access.

By default, ObjectDB accesses the fields directly, but accessing fields indirectly as properties using get and set methods is also supported:

```
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
```